# How to find/change login.jsp and dashboard ui from WSO2-IS before building the source code

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I downloaded the source code from the wso2/product-is repository(https://github.com/wso2/product-is) and build the code. I took the generated zip, unzipped it and ran the application. Everything went smooth. I now want to be able to change the login.jsp but I cannot find it anywhere in the repository or downloaded code.

In the zip I located it at the following path: /wso2is-5.8.0-beta2-SNAPSHOT/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint/login.jsp If I change it from here it will change the page but I don't want to change code on the deployed app.

I looked at the docs for wso2 but all I could find was this https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Customizing+Login+Pages+for+Service+Providers but this suggests I should change the code on the deployed application, not before building it.

My end goal is to customise the user dashboard and the login pages( and

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand is  user dashboard (jaggery) and the login pages (jsp) are two different applications. Customizing user dashboard is bit challenging because it was written in jaggery. Customizing login pages is not that difficult, if have a look inside the deployed product

`<product_home>`/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint you will see set of JSP pages which are responsible to show login page. If you carefully go through the steps near "Customizing Login page" in [1] you will understand the concept. To make it clear you don't need to build the product from source to customize login pages.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Customizing+Login+Pages+for+Service+Providers

Comment: I understand how to change the login files... I wanted to be able to have it in eclipse or an IDE in order to have access to the classes, etc. To change notifications and so on. 

Also this means that the user dashboard cannot be changed that easy ? I want to change the funtionality and look/feel a bit.

Answer (score 0):

java classes have been removed from authenticationendpoint web app in order provide customization capability without recompiling the code. Most of java classes relevant to authenticationendpoint you can find inside **org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util_5.12.153.jar** located in repository/components/plugins directory source [1]. Also you can find source code for authenticationendpoint web app [2].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/tree/v5.12.153/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util

[2] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/tree/v5.12.153/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint